# Can we create a template for sites in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, site-template

We have a lot of sites with SharePoint online with the same set of web parts. This is a team site; can I create a template so that we can create it from the templates?

Answer (score 8):

You can use Site Provisioning with PnP PowerShell. It gives you more control over what to include/exclude and automate the creation process if this is repetitive tasks.

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out C:\temp\template.pnp -PersistBrandingFiles 
New-PnPTenantSite -Url 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pnptempate' -Title 'New Site Collection' -Owner 'admin@domain.co.uk'
Connect-PnPOnline 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pnptempate'
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path C:\temp\template.pnp
```

More help/documentation about [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/GetPnPProvisioningTemplate.md) and [Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/ApplyPnPProvisioningTemplate.md).

More information about PnPSiteProvisioning [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Guidance/blob/551b9f6a66cf94058ba5497e310d519647afb20c/articles/Introducing-the-PnP-Provisioning-Engine.md)

Answer (score 6):

**Yes,** you can create a new site from the current customized site through `Save Site as Template` option in your `Site Setting`.

[image]

**Note:**

- Save site as a template is not available with a publishing site and community site

> For more details check **[MISSING SAVE SITE AS TEMPLATE IN SHAREPOINT](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-save-site-as-template-sharepoint-online/)**

- In SharePoint Online, if you disabled scripting capabilities for the affected site in Center Admin, this also removes the `Save site as template` option,

[image: https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-save-site-as-template-sharepoint-online/]

> check **[how to enable save site as template in SharePoint online](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-save-site-as-template-sharepoint-online/#enable-save-site-as-template-sharepoint-online)**

- `A site template` is like a blueprint for the site. Creating a site template allows you to capture your customizations so that they can be quickly applied to other SharePoint environments and even use the template as the basis for a business solution.
- **Save Site as Template:** Provide you to create a template from your site that you have customized for reuse through the below steps:

[image]

---

**For more details check**

- [How to save site as template in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-save-site-as-template-sharepoint-online/)
- [Save site as template option isn't available in SharePoint Online in Office 365 or SharePoint Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2492356)
- [Create and use site templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989)